# What is the Objective-C equivalent of the Java TimeZone?

Tags: java, objective-c, porting

What is the Objective-C equivalent of the Java TimeZone class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`NSTimeZone`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSTimeZone_Class/Reference/Reference.html), I believe. Can't say I've ever done any Objective-C myself, but it looks right...

Apple also has a (pretty short) [article on using it](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/DatesAndTimes/Articles/dtTimeZones.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000185).

It's quite likely that they won't be direct equivalents in *every* respect, of course... but if there's something you would use with Java's `TimeZone` which you can't figure out in `NSTimeZone`, ask about that specific call... and someone else can help you, I'm sure :)

EDIT: The *purpose* of a time zone class is to convert between local times in different time zones. For example, right now, it's 7.50pm for me - but it's 12.50pm for the person who I'm about to have a Skype call with. One option for representing dates and times is to always *store* them in UTC (which is sort of the "zero" of time zones) and then convert the UTC value into the "local" time for the user, e.g. for display purposes. That's not *always* the right option, but it's *usually* a good starting point.

At other times, you may *have* a local time and know person X's time zone - and want to convert it to person Y's time zone. It's *usually* easiest to do that by converting the local time to UTC (using X's time zone) and then to convert it back to local time using Y's time zone.

Time zones aren't nearly as straightforward as you might expect - mostly due to daylight savings. Oddities:

- Local times which either don't exist, or occur twice, due to DST transitions
- Time zones which change to DST at midnight, so that midnight doesn't always exist
- Governments deciding to scrap (or introduce) DST at almost no notice
- DST which *isn't* the normal "move an hour forwards". IIRC, Tibet was considering introducing DST of 1:15.
- Historical changes to time zones

The list goes on.

Comment: @Jon - I'm porting/rewriting a Java library for iOS. Bonus points for an explanation of the purpose of a TimeZone class.

Comment: Most of the headaches associated with time zones stem from two places: 1) time zones are a human construct and so tend to have lots of complex rules with minutiae aplenty; and 2) time zones have no bearing on the absolute value of a moment in time, but folks often think of 05:00:00 GMT being a different time from 00:00:00 EST, when in fact they're just two ways of describing the same instant. (The vagaries of relativity are irrelevant here.)

Answer (score 2):

The [NSTimeZone](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSTimeZone_Class/Reference/Reference.html) class is the equivalent of the Java TimeZone class.

Answer (score 1):

NSTimeZone : http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSTimeZone_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Regards.